# Get live stream health status using Youtube Data API V3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have access to a Youtube channel on my GSuite mail id xxxx@xxxx.com.
I am using Youtube Data API V3 to list live streams linked to that channel. (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams)
However, when I am trying to use this, I am getting below message: 
"Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
  try:
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=SCOPES, message="")
    storage = Storage(CLIENT_AUTH_FILE)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
      credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  except Exception as e:
    logger.info("ERROR: Exception from get_authenticated_service. " + str(e))

# Retrieve a list of the liveStream resources associated with the currently
# authenticated user's channel.
def list_streams(youtube):
    list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list(
      # part='id,snippet,status',
      part='snippet,status',
      mine=True,
      maxResults=50
    )
    if list_streams_request:
      list_streams_response = list_streams_request.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  youtube = get_authenticated_service()
  list_streams(youtube)
```

Comment: You probably have to wait until the APP is verified.

Comment: What is the process to verify the app? I am able to access live streams linked to my other gmail account without app being verified.

Comment: Any update on the above query ?